# How can I use a custom control class that inherits from a built-in control on my main form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

I have a mydatagridview class which inherits from the built-in `DataGridView` control, as shown below:

```
public class mydatagridview : DataGridView 
{
    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
        {
            this.ProcessTabKey(e.KeyData);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter) 
        {
            this.ProcessTabKey(keyData);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

Now I want to utilize it in my main class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**I want to Utilize myDatagridview with Datagridview1 of :    public partial class Form1 : Form**

How can I do this?

Comment: What's stopping you? could you state your problem more clearly?

Comment: flagging it, as "How to utilize" to start with then "how to utilize after adding it into form".

Comment: @Sanjeevkumar Hiremath, I didn't get it could you explain please.

Comment: @Sanjeevkumar: I didn't understand your last comment either. What do you mean? Flagging what?

Comment: @Cody what I meant is the OP needs to frame good, helpful questions, and the comments left by OP should be discouraged. That's the intent of flag. Nothing against your answer, infact I upvoted for the config info you've given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your custom control class, and then add that instance to your form's [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) collection. For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create an instance of your custom control
        mydatagridview myDGV = new mydatagridview();

        // Add that instance to your form's Controls collection
        this.Controls.Add(myDGV);
    }
}
```

---

Of course, you could also do the same thing from the Designer. It will automatically insert code very similar to that shown above inside the `InitializeComponent()` method.

If your custom control doesn't show up in the Toolbox automatically after you've rebuilt your project, make sure that you've [enabled toolbox auto-population](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw694kde.aspx):

1. From the "Tools" menu, select "Options".
2. Expand the "Windows Forms Designer" category.
3. Set the "AutoToolboxPopulate" property to True.

   [image: Set the AutoToolboxPopulate to True in VS Options]

Comment: Ok fine the control has been added to the class but how to utilise it with form1_load eventhandller for columns addition to Datagridview

Comment: @mahesh: If you add the control from the designer, it will automatically create a class-level variable corresponding to the instance of the control. If you add it manually through code, you'll have to declare such a variable yourself. Then, just add your columns by calling methods on that instance.

Comment: Yes You are right and thanks for suggested good link and nice narrated answer.

Comment: @mahesh, pick up a book on .Net Windows Forms and try reading these steps instead of leaving comment on every possible steps. **Adding back since OP has referenced it in one of his [post on META](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87705/learn-through-comment-is-this-sin)**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, and i'm not sure that I do, you can just use it like any other type:

```
mydatagridview mydatagrid = new mydatagridview();
this.Controls.Add(mydatagrid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Next to the answers that have already been given, it should be possible to drag and the drop the control from the toolbox to your form.

If you create a user control, or a custom Control, and build your project, the control should show up in the toolbox.